# Why I can't import csv file to MySQL through CMD by LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

I was trying to import csv file through CMD by LOAD DATA INFILE, because that csv file was large. But when try it that shows ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement.
Please help me with this. I searched the problem for many times but I didn't get an appropriate answer

I tried this code on cmd

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\Work\DATA\Movie data\ratings.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE movie_ratings
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Also, when after trying another method like this

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\ratings.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE movie_ratings
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

by moving the file to the path mentioned in secure_file_priv.
but even this that same error was showing.

Comment: *LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\ratings.csv'* - does this used filepath is local for MySQL server? or it is local for used client software?